# hive : drop table command does not remove table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am using sqoop  to import a table from mysql to Hive. Initially it got imported. Now, i want to drop this table. I use DROP table central. But, when i do Show tables, i can still see this table. Also, when i try to import the same table again in hive, i get the following error :

**Caused by: ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'UNIQUETABLE' defined on 'TBLS'.**

Comment: Could you provide your DROP TABLE Statement?

Comment: Drop table central;It works fine for other tables. But, this table 'central' was created using sqoop. Please suggest something

Comment: If your table is really named central then this should be no problem. Do you get an error when comitting the query?

Comment: I am using this command : bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/Traffic --username root -P --table central --hive-import -verbose -m 1 . This imported the table earlier. I made changes to this table in mysql and then dropped table in hive to import the updated table. But , this time it throws an exception as i pointed above

Comment: All I can say at this point is that the drop probably fails, dont know why. Maybe someone else can answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: Either you are dropping the table in MySQL itself or you are using a corrupt MySQL metastore.

Comment: @Carter Shanklin : I am not dropping a table in mysql. I imported a table from mysql to hive using sqoop . I am trying to drop a table in hive.